# How to make my program stop running when I press a certain key

Tags: python

My program is making a calculator and i made a option to restart. Basically if a user wants to continue, he press "y" and if he wants not to continue he press random letters or a certain letter. So could you help me on how to make a person stop running my program by pressing random keys or specific keys.

Here is my code:

```
def main():
num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
operator = input("Enter operator: ")
num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

if operator == "+":
  print(num1 + num2)
elif operator == "-":
  print(num1 - num2)
elif operator == "*":
  print(num1 * num2)
elif operator == "/":
  print(num1 / num2)
else:
    print("Error: Invalid operator")

restart = input("Do want to continue? Press \"y\" to continue or press any key to end ")
if restart == "y" or "Y":
    print("")
    main()
```

main()

**EDIT: THE exit() AND the import sys METHOD NOT WORKING**

Comment: `if restart == "y" or "Y":` could be reduced to `if restart.lower() == 'y':`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use sys.exit(). At the top of your code like here

```
    import sys
```

than in the finale part of your code implement the exit part

```
    restart = input("Do want to continue? Press \"y\" to continue or press any key to 
    end ")
    if restart == "y" or restart == "Y":
        print("")
        main()
    else:
        print("shutting down")
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: tried it but when i type random letter it did not stop running

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

...

if restart == "y" or "Y":
    print("")
    main()
else:
    sys.exit()
```

You can use the exit function in the `sys` module to quit when the user provides an input other than `y` or `Y`.

Comment: tried it but when i type random letter it did not stop running

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
import sys
def main():
    num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    operator = input("Enter operator: ")
    num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

    if operator == "+":
        print(num1 + num2)
    elif operator == "-":
        print(num1 - num2)
    elif operator == "*":
        print(num1 * num2)
    elif operator == "/":
       print(num1 / num2)
    else:
        print("Error: Invalid operator")

restart = input("Do want to continue? Press \"y\" to continue or press any key to end ")
if restart.lower() == "y":
    print("")
    main()
else:
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: tried it but when i type random letter it did not stop running

Answer (score -1):

It should be working like this:

```
a = input('Press a key to exit')
if a:
    exit(0)
```

In your code you could just add the else condition and put the `exit()` method inside it.

Comment: tried it but when i type random letter it did not stop running

Comment: remember that using the input() function need you to press enterr before going to the next line of code. Also, there was an error in my code, sorry, i updated it